# How to do update the list view by changing the drop-down item

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to change my list as I change my drop-down item..The list is dynamic so as I changed my option from drop-down..my list should update which will change only when that API that is called to form a list is changed by the selected drop-down item...The whole url will be same ,the only change is in the item.

```
      Future<ParsedDataModel> fetchTicketListData(String queueName) async {
  String openURL = "example.com/query=Queue='$queueName'";
         // hitting login api
      final response3 = await http.get(openURL);
     print(response3.body);
      if (response3.statusCode == 200 && response3.body.contains("200 Ok")) 
     {
  // parsing plain data to desired model
  ParsedDataModel ticketDataModel =
      DashBoardViewController().plainDataToParsedModelData(response3.body.trim());
  return ticketDataModel;
} else {
  throw Exception('There was a problem');
}
 }

   Future<List<QueueModel>> fetchTicketsList() async {
var dataList = await fetchTicketListData('InternalTools');
if (dataList.isNoResult) {
  throw Exception('No result found.');
} else {
  List<QueueModel> openTicketList = makeTicketList(dataList);
 openTicketsList = openTicketList;
  return openTicketsList;
       }
   }

   // function to parse the data into list of (QueueModel)
    List<QueueModel> makeTicketList(ParsedDataModel parsedData) {
     return 


   DashBoardViewController().parsedDataToQueueModelData(parsedData.dataList);
  }
```

Comment: Anyone knows this please do give answer

Comment: See, no one provided any hint because your question is too broad. Please add what you have tried and the way you fetching data from API. I will surely try to help.